# How to write to a already made .txt file python

Tags: python, text, tkinter, editor

I have made a very basic text editor where you can save to a new .txt file or open a existing text file. But I want to be able to where if the user opens a text file and hits the save button it replaces the file they opened with the new text. any ideas that can get me started?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

class Application(Frame):
def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.grid()
    self.Create_Widgets()

def Create_Widgets(self):
    self.SButton = Button(self,width=35)
    self.SButton["text"]="Save"
    self.SButton["command"]=self.Save
    self.SButton.grid(row=0,column=0)

    self.OButton = Button(self,width=35)
    self.OButton["text"]="Open"
    self.OButton["command"]=self.Open
    self.OButton.grid(row=0,column=1)

    self.Cont = Text(self,width=60,height=40)
    self.Cont.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)

def Save(self):
    Content=self.Cont.get(1.0,END)
    File = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    if File is None:
        return
    File.write(Content)
    File.close()

def Open(self):
    Content=self.Cont.get(0.0,END)
    File1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    File2 = open(File1,"r")
    Cont2 = File2.read()
    self.Cont.delete(1.0, END)
    self.Cont.insert(1.0, Cont2)

 root=Tk()
 root.title="Basic Notepad 0.1"


 app=Application(root)

 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: just write to the file. What issue are you having?

Comment: If you have file opened for reading than close it and open it for writing.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well I need to find the last file that was opened (Its location) then re write its contents but my just gives me a pop up to make a new file.

Comment: Then you have to remember file name and don't open pop up.

Comment: To remember the location of the prior file, merely write that to another file.

Comment: I have solved the problem by storing the text file you open in a variable and replacing that file with a new one with the same name but with the new text. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey @cdw100100 if you've found a solution to the question the best way to preserve it for people with a similar question is by creating an answer and accepting it.  Glad to hear you have a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Remember name of opened file (ex. `"old_name"`) and then use it in

```
tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(initialfile="old_name")
```

---

BTW: you could create button `SAVE` and `SAVE AS...`.
First one could write file without asking about name.

Comment: Can you explain this to me Ive never seen initial file in python before?

Comment: Run it and you see "old_name" in pop up in field for filename.

Comment: I have solved the problem by storing the text file you open in a variable and replacing that file with a new one with the same name but with the new text. Thanks for the help!